# Return Null - Rows.Retrieve() + Platform.Function.ParseJSON

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

i'm trying to get a specific field in a ssjs request, but the Platform.Function.ParseJSON returns null with the Stringify. Whe i try without the 'Stringify' returns 500 erros

but the 'Rows.Retrieve' works, the 'Write("The Value " + Stringify(data));' returns all the rows in DE.

```
       <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
    
    var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("...-E2D8-4864-99CF-69CBCCA1F950");
    var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
   if (typeof(data) == 'object' && data.length > 0) {
     var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Stringify(data));
     var val = obj.DataXML; 
     Write("The Value " + Stringify(val));
     Write("The Value " + Stringify(data));

    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse the response.  It's already JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a try/catch to trap any errors.  I think you're probably referring to `DataXML` improperly.  I'd suggest pasting the results into [jsonpathfinder.com](https://jsonpathfinder.com/) to find the correct reference to output it.

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

Platform.Load("core", "1");
var debug = true;

try {

  var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("...-E2D8-4864-99CF-69CBCCA1F950");
  var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();

  if (typeof(data) == 'object' && data.length > 0) {

    if (debug) {
      Write("<br>data: " + Stringify(data));
    }

    // loop through results here

  } else {
    Write("<br>No Rows Found");
  }

} catch (e) {

 if (debug) {
  Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
 }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. But the DataXML it's ok. This is the JSON response in Rows.Retrieve
My goal it's dsplay the: DataXML
[{"Invoice_Number__c":"",
"Base64Encode":"",
"AccountContract":"",
"DataXML":"",
"Name":"",
"InvoiceReference__c":"",
"EmissionDate__c":"",
"pURL":"",
"Id":"",
"BP_Id":"",
"DocumentNumber__c":"",
"InvoiceAccess__c":""}]

Comment: Then after the conditional you can refer to DataXML with: `data[0].DataXML`. You can't display XML directly, since your browser will try to render it.  You can do something like this:  `Write("DataXML: ", data[0].DataXML.replace("<","&lt;"))`

Comment: Thanks @Adam :D. With data[0].DataXML now i have the display value.